# Adding foldmarks in KOMA-script but NOT scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script

Is there an easy way to add foldmarks in KOMA-script classes?

I am aware of the foldmarks-option in `scrlttr2`, but that works only in `scrlttr2`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: You could use the eso-pic package

Comment: I would be very glad if there would be a more generic solution, that does not require to write the code for every possible papersize by hand.

Comment: for every possible papersize? I don't think this is possible since it depends on which envelope you use.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501278/48973) is applicable here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not quite sure if there is a solution for every possible papersize, if you want to stick to the DIN norm. The ratios in the example are according to the ratios of foldmarks on A4 paper. This generates foldmarks on the first page. 
Please note that I did not look up the correct positions or lengths for these marks on other paper sizes. With the values of 35.35%, 50% and 70.71% (`0.3535`, `0.50` & `0.7071`) this might not be the right values for non A4 paper.
Also these values are for a small letter head. For a large letter head you might want to adjust them to `1-0.3535`, `0.5` and `1-0.7071` accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw ($(current page.north west)!0.3535!(current page.south west)$)--++(0.5cm,0cm);
\draw ($(current page.north west)!0.50!(current page.south west)$)--++(0.8cm,0cm);
\draw ($(current page.north west)!0.7071!(current page.south west)$)--++(0.5cm,0cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Example pages with foldmarks, as generated by the code (can the size of this be scaled down, please?)]

Comment: According to DIN 5008, the marks on an DIN A4 sheet should be at 210mm and 105mm measured either from top or bottom depending on how tall the letterhead is. These sizes are the width and half the width, i. e. h/√2 (0.7071) and h/2×√2 (0.3536).