# Place the sender address on the left side in moderncv cover letter

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

In Germany it's common to place both the sender and recipient on the left side of a letter and the date on the right side.

Is there a possibility that I can change the cover letter layout accordingly?

```
\recipient{Stack Overflow GmbH}{Stack Überflut Straße-71234-Codehausen}

\date{04 Oktober 2013}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Frau XYZ,}
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
\makelettertitle

bla bla bla blu blu blu

\makeletterclosing
```

So that my address appears over the recipient address on the left side?

Comment: Can you post some compilable code to see what you have in your letter?

Comment: As you seems to be a German please have a look to my answer to the question [introducing-courtesy-folding-marks-in-moderncv](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132020/introducing-courtesy-folding-marks-in-moderncv/132123#132123)

Answer (score 4):

Under the `classic` style, [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) sets the letter opening in a specific way. Consider the following visual:

[image]

The sender address (top right) is contained in a `minipage` that is flush-right, set in `\raggedleft` and spans 50% of the `\textwidth`. This is followed by a `1em` vertical gap, and then the recipient address (bottom left), set in a `minipage` that is flush-left, set in `\raggedright` and spans 50% of the `\textwidth`. Finally, an `\hfill` pushes the "date box" flush-right.

Depending on where you want these boxes to be located, they're pretty easy to move around and/or reformat in terms of their layout. Here's one example:

[image]

which stems from adding

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\hfill}{}{}{}% Sender address flush-left
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\raggedleft}{\raggedright}{}{}% Sender address \raggedright
```

to your document preamble. The above adjustment is dependent on the `classic` style as it directly patches `\makelettertitle` as its defined in [`moderncvstyleclassic.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstyleclassic.sty). Other options also exist, depending on where you want the date to be placed (vertically or otherwise).