# Place the sender address on the left side in moderncv cover letter 2

Tags: moderncv

I have the same problem as the questioner here: [Address on the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136433/place-the-sender-address-on-the-left-side-in-moderncv-cover-letter)

However, the proposed solution doesn't work anymore. What is the new solution to this problem?

Best regards