# Folding marks to the background of page

Tags: watermark

An A4 paper made with LaTeX should be horizontally folded to three parts. I would like to have something like two dashed gray lines below text going from edge to edge - kind of like a watermark. Is this possible?

(Last third of the page will contain an address, first two thirds has message. Hence a minipage with border is not a perfect solution.)

Comment: Yes, it is: see the `eso-pic` package. Would it be for a single page, or for all (even/odd) pages of a document?

Comment: @Bernard, eso-pic seems to fit but has no documentation. For all pages with one command would be preferable.

Comment: Do you print two-sided or one sided?

Comment: @Bernard, one-sided. These will finally be separated to one-page PDFs, but they all will have same basic format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short code with `eso-pic` and `dashrule`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\color{lightgray}%
\AtPageLowerLeft{\hdashrule[0.667\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}{6pt 3pt}}%
\AtPageLowerLeft{\hdashrule[0.333\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}{6pt 3pt}}}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and great!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this using `\AddEverypageHook` from the [everypage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/everypage) package to add some lines to the page using [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZ) and [TikZpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZpagenodes). Basically, you use the page nodes provided by [TikZpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZpagenodes) to draw horizontal lines one third and two thirds of the way down every page.

Here are some of the pages produced by the MWE below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[gray!50,dashed]($(current page.north west)!0.33!(current page.south west)$)
          --($(current page.north east)!0.33!(current page.south east)$);
    \draw[gray!50,dashed]($(current page.north west)!0.66!(current page.south west)$)
          --($(current page.north east)!0.66!(current page.south east)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

  \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Personally, I find the the lines going all the way across the page to be a little too distracting and would instead go for something like:

[image]

Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \foreach \side/\offset/\pos in {west/1/0.33, west/1/0.66, east/-1/0.33, east/-1?0.66} {
      \draw[gray!50, thin]($(current page.north \side)!\pos!(current page.south \side)$)--++(\offset,0);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

  \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but it does not divide to three parts of same size. I guess it starts measuring from the printable area, not from the real page start.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `eso-pic` like suggested by [@Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562471/folding-marks-to-the-background-of-page#comment1417948_562471).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[]{color}


\AddToShipoutPictureBG
  {%
    \textcolor{gray}
      {%
        \multiput
          (0,\LenToUnit{\paperheight/3})
          (\LenToUnit{0.02\paperwidth},0)
          {50}
          {\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{0.01\paperwidth}}}
        \multiput
          (0,\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/3})
          (\LenToUnit{0.02\paperwidth},0)
          {50}
          {\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{0.01\paperwidth}}}
      }
  }

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also good, but the marks are slightly off. (I added `a4paper`-option to `documentclass`.)

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo they aren't off in my PDF-viewer. Which viewer are you using? If in doubt, pick `xpdf`. If you're using Adobe's viewer: Never trust it, it's rendering rather poorly and imprecise especially if zoomed out.

Comment: I don't get... I really printed this. But now I tested with Gimp (xpdf did not install) and everything is OK. I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo depending on your printers driver setting, the logical PDF page might get slightly resized to fit into the physically printable margins of your printer.